# org.hibernate.MappingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Employee

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and using hibernate version 4.3.4 JAR files. I'm trying to execute simple Hibernate program using mySQL server in intelliJ community edition. Below are my files.

POJO File

```
package TestPackage;
public class Employee {
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int salary;

public Employee() {}
public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.salary = salary;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId( int id ) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
    this.firstName = first_name;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
    this.lastName = last_name;
}
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary( int salary ) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
}
```

Mapping File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the employee detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
    <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate Config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

    </property>
    <!-- Related to the connection END -->
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://v-dev-        sql:1433;database=SIMSevals;integratedSecurity=true</property>
    <property name="connection.user">deptisg</property>
    <property name="connection.password">IsgDev1</property>

    <!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Related to hibernate properties END -->

    <!-- Related to mapping START -->
    <mapping resource="testpackage/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <!-- Related to the mapping END -->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Main Class

```
 package TestPackage;

    import java.sql.*;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

    import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
    //import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;`enter code here`


public class hibernate {
//private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;`enter code here`

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {

    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://okeechobee.synygy.net:1433;database=SIMSNotes;integratedSecurity=true");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://v-dev-sql:1433;database=SIMSevals;integratedSecurity=true");

        //Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");


        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        System.out.println("test34534543");
        ServiceRegistry sr = new   StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();


        SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(sr);

        Session session = sf.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();


        //Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Integer employeeID = null;


        conn.close();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Stack trace

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7546 "-                              Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Users\vazek\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition                14.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:    \Program         Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib  \javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java    \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib   \jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre    \lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre    \lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files  \Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext    \antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\avro-1.7.6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre    \lib\ext\commons-  codec-1.6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\commons-compress-1.5.jar;C:\Program     Files  \Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\commons-io-2.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\commons-lang-      2.6.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext \dom4j- 1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\hibernate-commons-annotations- 4.0.5.Final.jar;C:  \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Program  Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre \lib\ext\hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java  \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\hibernate-jpa-    2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext  \hibernate-search-analyzers-    4.5.2.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\hibernate-   search-infinispan-4.5.2.Final.jar;C:    \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\infinispan-commons-    6.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java   \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext \infinispan-lucene-directory-6.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java  \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jackson-core-asl- 1.9.13.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jackson-  mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Program Files\Java \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\javassist-3.18.1-   GA.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext   \jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar;C:\Program Files\Java   \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jboss-logging-annotations-    1.2.0.Beta1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext  \jboss-marshalling-1.4.4.Final.jar;C:   \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jboss-marshalling-river-   1.4.4.Final.jar;C:\Program Files    \Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-  1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java   \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jgroups-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Program Files\Java \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jms-  1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\Program    Files\Java  \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:  \Program    Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-analyzers-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib       \ext\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-grouping-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program      Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-highlighter-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext     \lucene-kuromoji-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-memory-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program        Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-misc-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-        phonetic-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-smartcn-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files     \Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-spatial-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-      spellchecker-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\lucene-stempel-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program       Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\solr-        analysis-extras-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\solr-core-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files       \Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\solr-solrj-3.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sqljdbc4.jar;C:      \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext       \sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java     \jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\xml-apis-1.3.03.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users     \vazek\Desktop\Hibernate2\out\production\Hibernate2;C:\Users\vazek\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA      Community Edition 14.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain         TestPackage.hibernate
hello 22ed
test1
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties:      {hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.service.allow_crawling=false,       hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.max_fetch_depth=5, hibernate.format_sql=true,      hibernate.generate_statistics=true, hibernate.connection.username=sa,       hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE,       hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true,        hibernate.connection.pool_size=5}
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace       http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: testpackage/Employee.hbm.xml
test34534543
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
test21
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://v-        dev-sql:1433;database=SIMSevals;integratedSecurity=true]
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=deptisg, password=****}
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl     configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 5 (min=1)
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:38 AM org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect <init>
WARN: HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator      initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Dec 11, 2014 11:40:39 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
org.hibernate.MappingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Employee
```

Please help.

Comment: In your hibernate config i think you forget to close a ">" in the driver prorperty

Comment: It is closed just the closing tag is pasted on the new line in above example.

Answer (score 2):

Use full class path in you hibernate mapping file and check.use   :
`class name="TestPackage.Employee"`

`<class name="TestPackage.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add
`<context:component-scan base-package="TestPackage"/>` in Hibernate Config file.

Answer (score 0):

Following line in mapping file should be changed from

```
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
```

to

```
<class name="TestPackage.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
```

Full path of entity should be specified in hibernate mapping files.